# Windows' Git errors out with 'permission denied (public key)' when trying to access BitBucket via 'git pull' even though the ssh-key is correct

Tags: windows-10, ssh, git, openssh, bitbucket.org

I'm running:

- Windows 10 (latest updates)
- Git version 'git version 2.36.1.windows.1'
- SSH -V returns:

  ```
   OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
  ```

In the properties-dialog all executables inside C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH* display:

```
    product version: 8.1.0.1
```

(this is the default suite that Windows10 maintains - I never laid a finger on it myself)

- The 'ssh-agent' is up and running 'ssh-add -l' displays both of my keys:

  ```
  3072 SHA256:.... <blahblah> (RSA)
  2048 SHA256:.... C:\foo\bar\key.ppk (RSA)
  ```

These exact same keys are also used inside WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04) and they work just fine.

- When I try to run 'git pull' on any of my **BitBucket** repos I get the following error:

  ```
    permission denied (public key)'
  ```

The exact same command works fine in Ubuntu 20.04 with the exact same keys loaded in 'ssh-agent'. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that 'git' has some sort of pet-peeve with BitBucket when it comes to using its built-in OpenSSH libraries in Windows10.

I resorted to reinstalling 'git' altogether but this time around I made sure to have git employ the OpenSSH suite provided by Windows10 itself (instead of git's built-in OpenSSH suite) and once that was done everything started working as intended.

PS: People more knowledgeable on OpenSSH / BitBucket / Git can shed some more light as to why the built-in 'OpenSSH' suite doesn't work - such things lay outside the realms of my capabilities for the time being.

[image: Git installation]

PS#2: if you want to avoid reinstalling 'git' just to tweak this particular setting then you can simply try (haven't tested it myself though):

```
    git config --global core.sshCommand "C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe"
```

Comment: The git config value appears to be parsed twice for some reason; I had to edit the line in .gitconfig manually to be  `sshCommand = "C:\\\\Program\\ Files\\\\OpenSSH-Win64\\\\ssh.exe"`